# Use Data API to access position value of image being loaded

Tags: javascript, php, variables, bootstrap-4

Maybe is another stupid question but it's driving me crazy.
Basically I've got this form to input 20 images (generated by a for)

```
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i<20; $i++)
        {

          echo '<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6">';
          echo '<div class="file-field">';
          echo '<div class="z-depth-1-half mb-4" id="thumb-output'.$i.'"></div>';
          echo '<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">';
          echo '<div class="custom-file">';
          echo '<input type="file" name="field'.$i.'" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile'.$i.'" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon'.$i.'">';
          echo '<label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile'.$i.'">Choose file</label>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '';
          echo '<div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-6">';
          echo '</div>';

        }
 ?>
```

I need to show a Thumbinail before the uploading, at the moment it works just for one of the fields (#inputGroupFile3 and #thumb-output3).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#inputGroupFile3').on('change', function(){ //on file input change
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) //check File API supported browser
        {
            $('#thumb-output3').html(''); //clear html of output element
            var data = $(this)[0].files; //this file data

            $.each(data, function(index, file){ //loop though each file
                if(/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i.test(file.type)){ //check supported file type
                    var fRead = new FileReader(); //new filereader
                    fRead.onload = (function(file){ //trigger function on successful read
                    return function(e) {
                        var img = $('<img/>').addClass('thumb img-fluid img-thumbnail').attr('src', e.target.result); //create image element
                        $('#thumb-output3').append(img); //append image to output element
                    };
                    })(file);
                    fRead.readAsDataURL(file); //URL representing the file's data.
                }
            });

        }else{
            alert("Your browser doesn't support File API!"); //if File API is absent
        }
    });
});
```

Basically what I need to have is something like in the PHP code `(id="thumb-output'.$i.')` but in JS, something like:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#inputGroupFile<b>$i</b>').on('change' [...]
```

`[...]$('#thumb-output<b>$i</b>').append(img)[...]`

Thank you.

Comment: Why not attach that handler on class `.custom-file-input` instead of making it ID specific(like `#inputGroupFile3`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.data()` api to get the ID number, for that add an attribute say **index** in following line

```
echo '<input type="file" data-index="'.$i.'" name="field'.$i.'" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile'.$i.'" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon'.$i.'">';
```

this attribute would be available in your jQuery event handler which you should change to be a generic one & not ID specific.

```
$('.custom-file-input').on('change', function(){ 
//on file input change, (#inputGroupFile3 changed to .custom-file-input as 
//it will listen to all images with that class).

var index = jQuery(this).data('index'); 
//this should now hold the index value of the current image like 1 or 2 or 3 so on,
///use the variable where ever you need the ID number.

//Rest of the handler body
```

Comment: Thank You so much, you saved my brain from collapsing :)